# How to stop firebase listening when its already loaded on given location in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, bottom-sheet

Here i used firebase with new variable within a BottomSheetDialogFragment.
The fundamental is

1. click button from activity.
2. open bottomsheet
3. load firebase data
4. show loaded firebase data in bottom sheet

Activity code

```
onCLick
{
BottomSheet BottomSheet=new BottomSheet();
                BottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"List");
}
```

BottomSheet class

```
private DatabaseReference UserRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_list_layout,container,false);
        initialize(v);
        return v;
    }
private void initialize(View v)
    {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
 UserRef.child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                        {
                            Villaz villaz=dataSnapshot.getValue(Villaz.class);
                          
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
}
```

So, My question is how do i stop loading data from firebase if bottom sheet is already opened first time,
Is it possible when bottom sheet open first time, loaded firebase data saved in somewhere and load it when bottom sheet open second time, until user standing over the activity (reason: reduce firebase costing)

Comment: addListenerForSingleValueEvent is indeed obly load data for one time only when its Siting fragment get opened,   the problem is you didnt save the current data, in your code you always re-asking firebase for data. you can initilize firebase from within actiivity, and save its data to activity viewmodel,and then simply observe the data from viewmodel

Comment: the loading data is in heavy size, so it will not recommended to initialize in activity beacause it is not necessary, but whenever open than saved it